# Twitter4j - Build a graph composed by tweets and their respectives retweets

Tags: twitter4j

I need to build a graph in which some nodes are tweets and others are retweets which point to their respective tweets. I start my application doing a search for some subject, let's say "computer". Then, I gather some number of tweets that contains that subject. From there, I want to search for the retweets of these tweets and then, build my network by linking ones to the others. 
The problem is that when I try to search for retweets of a tweet using its id, the application throws an exception saying that authentication credentials are missing. Is there a way of getting these retweets without requiring external authentication ('cause my app is not interactive), I mean, is it possible that I can get these information only with my credentials (login,password)?

Maybe that's a silly question I've asked about, but since I'm a beginner at this API and Twitter as well, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

using Twitter4J? try invoking getReTweets() method. More documentation [here](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/api/StatusMethods.html#getRetweets%28long%29).

Answer (score 0):

Read carefully point Number 7 in samples [here](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html). Authentication credentials means there are 4 Strings. Two of your application(consumer keys) and Two of the user(access Tokens) using application.